# Getting this error "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)" while compiling opencv contours

Tags: python, opencv

I'm going to run an openCV people counting tutorial code. tutorials are available here. https://fedemejia.com/?p=68 
but while i'm running the following code by cmd. I'm getting this error

File "VideoCapture.py", line 25, in 
    _, contours0, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

my python version is 3.6.8
opencv 4.0.0

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('peopleCounter.avi') #Open video file
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(detectShadows = True) #Create the background substractor
kernelOp = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
kernelCl = np.ones((11,11),np.uint8)
areaTH = 500

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read() #read a frame

    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame) #Use the substractor
    try:
        ret,imBin= cv2.threshold(fgmask,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        #Opening (erode->dilate) para quitar ruido.
        mask = cv2.morphologyEx(imBin, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernelOp)
        #Closing (dilate -> erode) para juntar regiones blancas.
        mask =  cv2.morphologyEx(mask , cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernelCl)
    except:
        #if there are no more frames to show...
        print('EOF')
        break

    _, contours0, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    for cnt in contours0:
        cv2.drawContours(frame, cnt, -1, (0,255,0), 3, 8)
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        print area
        if area > areaTH:
            #################
            #   TRACKING    #
            #################
            M = cv2.moments(cnt)
            cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
            cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
            cv2.circle(frame,(cx,cy), 5, (0,0,255), -1)
            img = cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

    cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)

    #Abort and exit with 'Q' or ESC
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release() #release video file
cv2.destroyAllWindows() #close all openCV windows
```

It was supposed to give the result describe in the tutorial.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=findcontours%20unpack

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In OpenCV 4.0, `cv2.findContour()` returns only 2 values. So it should be `contours0, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)`. See here https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d0d/tutorial_find_contours.html

Comment: is not it written same there? 
what should i change ?

Comment: before 4.0 it's `_, contours0, hierarchy`, after 4.0 it's only `contours0, hierarchy`.

Comment: thanks i got it. it works. "_," this has to be removed.